# Search for clipboard text in emacs

Tags: emacs

is it possible to search for the text that currently is present in the clipboard when hitting `C-s`, probably with some sort of hook that is triggered when hitting `C-s` and then inserts the clipboard into the minibuffer?

Comment: See also [this question](http://superuser.com/q/221829/4542).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Isearch](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IncrementalSearch#MoreIsearchKeys) provides a set of standard keys to change the behaviour of the search process. Typing <kbd>C-s M-y</kbd> invokes `isearch-yank-kill` that pulls string from kill ring (i.e., clipboard) into search string.

Comment: To see all `isearch` keybindings (and other help), type `C-s C-h C-h`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Kill-ring and clipboard are different things, and e.g. for me both C-y and M-y for isearching paste random junk neither of which I have in secondary or primary clipboards.

Answer (score 1):

You could yank the text after starting isearch:

```
(defun my-isearch-yank-clipboard ()
  (interactive)
  (isearch-yank-string (or (x-get-selection 'PRIMARY)
                           (x-get-selection 'CLIPBOARD)
                           "")))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-s c") 'my-isearch-yank-clipboard)
```

Start isearch then "M-s c"

Comment: @scottfrazer: Built-in `(isearch-yank-x-selection)` does exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use defadvice to alter the behaviour of the command isearch-forward, that is bound by default to C-s, or define another function that maybe wraps isearch-forward and bind it to C-s in place of isearch-forward.